# TTreeNode blinking. How do I make that?

Tags: delphi, treeview

I like to have a blinking node. How can I make that?

Comment: Unless the application is for your own personal use, please, please, please, don't make anything blink. It's distracting and annoying. Just like animations and other "please look at me" UI "feaures".

Answer (score 4):

The below is by no means a complete solution, but a simple example of David's answer:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    TreeView1: TTreeView;
    Timer1: TTimer;
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure TreeView1CustomDrawItem(Sender: TCustomTreeView; Node: TTreeNode;
      State: TCustomDrawState; var DefaultDraw: Boolean);
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FHighTime: Boolean;
    FHighNode: TTreeNode;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
  R: TRect;
begin
  if Assigned(FHighNode) then begin
    FHighTime := not FHighTime;
    FHighNode.MakeVisible;
    R := FHighNode.DisplayRect(True);
    InvalidateRect(TreeView1.Handle, @R, True);
  end else begin
    if FHighTime then
      TreeView1.Invalidate;
    FHighTime := False;
    Timer1.Enabled := False;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.TreeView1CustomDrawItem(Sender: TCustomTreeView;
  Node: TTreeNode; State: TCustomDrawState; var DefaultDraw: Boolean);
const
  Colors: array [Boolean] of TColor = (clWindowText, clWindow);
  HiColors: array [Boolean] of TColor = (clHighlightText, clHighlight);
begin
  if Node = FHighNode then begin
    if cdsSelected in State then
      TreeView1.Canvas.Font.Color := HiColors[FHighTime]
    else
      TreeView1.Canvas.Font.Color := Colors[FHighTime];
  end;
end;


procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // test
  FHighNode := TreeView1.Items[2];
  Timer1.Enabled := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FHighNode := nil;
end;
```

You might like to change the design so that setting a highlight node is like calling a setter, etc.. But anyway, you get the idea..

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing built in to the common control to achieve this so you'll need to do it yourself.

Use a `TTimer` and each time it fires, change whatever property of the node you need to achieve the blinking effect.